# How to clear Jenkins Heap memory if completely occupied

Tags: jenkins

I have Jenkins application running on a VM, and somehow all the system memory was completely occupied, How do I clean up the memory? And How do I know how much of heap memory is allocated and how can we clear the heap memory?

```
cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:       132046272 kB
MemFree:        63724320 kB
Buffers:          155484 kB
Cached:         17920672 kB
SwapCached:         5108 kB
Active:         26331416 kB
Inactive:        9676204 kB
Active(anon):   17778452 kB
Inactive(anon):   153136 kB
Active(file):    8552964 kB
```

Comment: "Have you tried turning it off and on again" -  The IT crowd

Comment: Yes, it helps temporarily, But I run into this issue again

Comment: Maybe focus on finding why so memory is used instead of clearing it forcefully.

Answer (score 6):

1. Install [Monitoring](https://plugins.jenkins.io/monitoring) plugins
2. In browser, http://YOUR_JENKINS_URL/monitoring
3. On top of the webpage, call GC by clicking on *Execute the garbage collector*
4. If you want to call the GC from script, look at *Execute GC* section [HERE](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Monitoring+Scripts)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try rebooting Jenkins, and if so, the VM itself ?
I'd say it's the simplest - yet the most effective way.

Comment: Yeah, I have restarted the application and it cleared the memory for me temporarily, again the same issue kicks of after few days.

Comment: Did you solve this ? What was the issue ? Otherwise, if you are not able to identify, maybe a daily reboot would be fine ?

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins itself is running in a Java Virtual Machine (JVM) and this JVM can be configured (heap_size and more). If you have not enough memory for your virtual machine you have to decrease the memory of the JVM. You will do this in the server.xml file of the jenkins with some Parameters. In the best case you will give your vm more memory. Here is an example of this arguments:

JAVA_ARGS="-Xmx256m"   # <--default value

JAVA_ARGS="-Xmx2048m"

How to configure your jenkins correctly please consult the [documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/)
and this [page](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Administering+Jenkins) and here is [page](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E22289_01/html/821-1274/configuring-the-default-jvm-and-java-arguments.html) for the jvm arguments.

Answer (score 0):

On a production instance, a daily reboot is not a suggested option. I had the heap memory cleared it through "Monitoring" plugin and also upgraded to 2.x (say 2.65 or 2.89.4) version of Jenkins and it solved my issue