# How to execute the garbage collector in a Jenkinsfile pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, garbage-collection

I have a Jenkinsfile:

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Install dependencies') {
      steps {
        sh 'yarn'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can I execute the Java garbage collector in the pipeline script?

This [related question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54373885/3689364) hints at the monitoring plugin but you still have to manually click with it.

Answer (score 0):

Run the garbage collector in a pipeline script:

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Run garbage collector') {
      steps {
        script {
          System.gc();
        }
      }
    }
    stage('Install dependencies') {
      steps {
        sh 'yarn'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

- On first execution, this job will fail. In the console output you will find an error:

  > Scripts not permitted to use staticMethod java.lang.System gc. Administrators can decide whether to approve or reject this signature.
- You can approve the script signature here: https://jenkins.YOUR_URL.com/scriptApproval/
- allow java.lang.System gc

Solved when I found this [issue](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-66561).